# Bounding Rect for String in a label

Tags: ios, objective-c, bounding-box

I am trying to get the bounding rect for an attributed string in a label, but I am just able to get the size, not the origin. Do you guys know what's wrong in my method and why it doesn't return the proper origin?

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectForString:(NSAttributedString *)attributedstring label:(UILabel *)label
{
    CGRect labelSizeRect = [attributedstring boundingRectWithSize:label.bounds.size
                                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                           context:nil];

    return labelSizeRect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `boundingRectForString` only returns the rect of the attributed string.

If you want to get the origin you need to look at the frame of the label `yourLabel.frame.origin`.

Comment: But I meed the origin of the attributed string within the label, I don't need the label origin.

Answer (score 0):

The origin for the text within the label is (0,0) - since the bounding box only calculates the proper width/height.
The position for the label is label.frame.origin

**Update**:

[image: Blue box = UILabel, green box = surrounding rect around the string]

To get the **purple X** position:

```
CGRect boundingRect = [attributedstring boundingRectWithSize:label.bounds.size
                                                       options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                       context:nil];
y_origin = (label.frame.size.height - boundingRect.height) / 2;
// x_origin is 0 when left aligned, for centered it is:
x_origin = (label.frame.size.width - boundingRect.width) / 2;
```

While on the other hand, if you want the position of the string in the bounding box, it is obviously (0,0)

Comment: Any way to get the origin of the string within the label then?